# Rails render template or partial but executing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, view, partials

I'm trying to show info into a dialog. I want such info to be loaded from a view (template). The thing is that, when i use

```
<%= render template:'panels/product_specifications' %>
```

it tries to load the info but, as i have global variables used in my view that were defined in the controller, and the controller isn't executed it throws me:

```
undefined method `banner_image_with_arrows_filename' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: 
2: - banner_image = "banners/panels/#{@panel.banner_image_with_arrows_filename}"
3: #image-info
4:   %table
5:     %tr
```

@panel variable is defined in controller here:

```
def load_panel
    @panel = Panel.find_or_build_from_id(params[:id])
    if !@panel.available_in_market?(market)
      add_flash_notice(t("pages.panel.text.not_available_in_market", :market => market.name), true)
    end
end
```

in a `before_filter`.

I have also tried with `render partial:'panels/products_specifications` (having underscored 'product_specifications.html.erb' first), `render action:'panels/product_specifications', controller:'product_specifications` with different errors.

How can i load that partial or view from another with the controller being executed too?

EDIT:

To give you a big picture, what i'm trying to do is to show the user (when he passes the mouse over a link) a dialog with a preview of what he will see if he click that link.

Comment: Where are you calling `render_to_string`? In a view?

Comment: `render partial:'panels\products_specifications` is that the right path ? It should have been `render partial: 'panels/products_specifications'`

Comment: @polarblau: sorry, i must have been very sleepy when i post the question. I have corrected ir with only `render` and `render partial: 'panels/products_specifications'` as it is how i did it in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand as well, you hit a action that execute the method `load_panel` with a before_filter and, the view associated, you're trying to render a template with the variable.

The first thing you should to try is to see if there is a record returned by `Panel.find_or_build_from_id(params[:id])`. You can use the `puts` method or use a debugger like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry).

You can also try to do this `<%= render template:'panels/product_specifications', panel: @panel %>` and use `panel` as a local variable in your template like this : `banners/panels/#{panel.banner_image_with_arrows_filename}`.

I think a best practices can be to use a [presenter](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html).

---

**Final answer after a chat**

You must to use ajax to show a new panel and hit a controller action. You can see an example [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?autoplay=true).

Comment: it never gets to the controller. I have put a `debugger` breakpoint and also a `puts "------------------------"` to be printed in the console, but it never gets there. I don't know if `render` doesn't make use of the controller,. i can't use `<%= render template:'panels/product_specifications', panel: @panel %>`, since @panel is not defined in the page i have the links that will show the dialog on click

Comment: render will not hit a controller method. You must to use a presenter or create the variable on the controller's action used with the route.

Comment: it's not a controller method, is the action. Maybe i'm missunderstanding something. here it is my controller, view and route http://fpaste.org/64549/.
What is a presenter?

Comment: For presenters, read this http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html or watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch.

Comment: If I understand, the main problem is than the action `product_specifications` is never triggered. Try to replace your route with this `get '/panels/product_specifications'` (add a `/` at the beggining).

Comment: From the panel's index view, i have links to products show views, when the the show view is visited it defines the @panel and other variables on the controller. I exctracted a portion of code from the show view, and created a new view called product_specifications. That 'product_specifications' view i want to show it in a dialog with render method, but as the render doesn't hit the controller, the variables are never set so it throws me an error of nil class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44006/discussion-between-dougui-and-jgutierrezc)